# How to expand the Taylor series of functions of several vectors?

Tags: matrices, power-series, taylor-expansion, tensor-products

We know that the Taylor series expansion of the function of several scalars around zero is
$$
f(x,y)=f(0,0)+f_x(0,0)\cdot x+f_y(0,0)\cdot y+\frac{1}{2!}f_{xx}(0,0)\cdot x^2+\dots
$$

Then, how about the function of several vectors $f({\bf x,y}):\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$? What is the best way to express its Taylor series that it maintains the same structure of the scalar case, i.e. similar to the above expression?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean a real-valued function of several vectors? For example, is $$f:\mathbb R^2\times \mathbb R^2 \to\mathbb R$$ the sort of thing you have in mind?

Comment: @MPW Yes, this is the case what I addressed.

Comment: What do you mean by multi vector valued! It seems strange to me! what is the difference between $f({\bf{x}})$ and $f({\bf{x}},{\bf{y}})$? mmmmmmm, The best I can imagine is the **determinant function** which coincide with your terminology! :) It is a function of the form
$$f: \underbrace{\mathbb R^n\times  ... \times \mathbb R^n}_{n\,\,\text{times}} \to\mathbb R$$

Comment: @H.R. Yes, you are right. Sorry for my misleading words. Now, I update my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**

If $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is a function denoted by $f({\bf{x}})$then we have by Taylor series

$$f({\bf{x}})=f({\bf{x}}_0)+\nabla f({\bf{x}}_0) \cdot ({\bf{x}}-{\bf{x}}_0) + \frac{1}{2} ({\bf{x}}-{\bf{x}}_0) \cdot \nabla \nabla f ({\bf{x}}_0) \cdot ({\bf{x}}-{\bf{x}}_0) + \cdot \cdot \cdot \tag{1}$$

Now, if $f:\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ denoted by $f({\bf{x}},{\bf{y}})$ we can use the above formula to get

$$f({\bf{x}},{\bf{y}})=f({\bf{x}}_0,{\bf{y}})+\nabla_{\bf{x}} f({\bf{x}}_0,{\bf{y}}) \cdot ({\bf{x}}-{\bf{x}}_0) + \frac{1}{2} ({\bf{x}}-{\bf{x}}_0) \cdot \nabla_{\bf{x}} \nabla_{\bf{x}} f ({\bf{x}}_0,{\bf{y}}) \cdot ({\bf{x}}-{\bf{x}}_0) + \cdot \cdot \cdot \tag{2}$$

then you should repeat the expansion for ${\bf{y}}$ in each term of the RHS of $(2)$. Specifically, you may write the expansions of $f({\bf{x}}_0,{\bf{y}})$, $\nabla_{\bf{x}} f({\bf{x}}_0,{\bf{y}})$ and $\nabla_{\bf{x}} \nabla_{\bf{x}} f ({\bf{x}}_0,{\bf{y}})$ at ${\bf{y}}={\bf{y}}_0$. Notice that in the expansions in ${\bf{y}}$ you have $\nabla_{\bf{y}}$ instead of $\nabla_{\bf{x}}$. I just leave the arithmetic to you.

Comment: What about mixed partials between the "x" variables and the "y" variables? Or are you talking about expanding the derivatives themselves, so that you wind up with multiple remainder terms?

Comment: @Ian: Yes, I may modify my $\nabla$ to $\nabla_{\bf{x}}$ to make this clear! :)

Comment: Is this formula $\frac{1}{2} ({\bf{x}}-{\bf{x}}_0) \cdot \nabla \nabla f ({\bf{x}}_0) \cdot ({\bf{x}}-{\bf{x}}_0)$ a scalar ($\in\mathbb R$)? In addition, I am curious about the third order term. How to write it? Your idea is great, but I more concern about the details, sorry.

Comment: @user143763: Yes, it is a scalar! It is quadratic form. I leave the details to you. :) I don't know about the third order term but there should be something. :)